# What manga is Mur Mur reading?

Tags: mirai-nikki

In the anime Mur Mur reads manga sometimes. What are these manga?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's a fictional manga magazine featuring a few different chapters from different series.  The word シュシュ in japanese means an elastic band of some sort.

Comment: I don't have any context to base this on, but シュシュhere could be an irregular way to write しゅうしゅう (collection/variety), which might make more sense than naming it after scrunchies.

Comment: @LoganM yeah, I believe you might be right on that one.

Answer (score 0):

To me the first one looks like a manga magazine. So it includes more than one manga. And the magazine is called "Shushu". I assume it is a fictional magazine since I can't seem to find information about it.